# how to create 2 rows and required amount of columns layout using grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to create a layout something like shown in below photo.

[image]

I tried using this code below.

```
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
grid-auto-flow: column;
```

but, the result I got was not really I am looking for (SS below of the output from above code)

[image]

How can I create the grid layout like shown in first photo?

Comment: That's expected. You are flowing as a column so Naturally the cells run down. Just remove the auto flow and you get a row. The empty cell is a separate issue which you will have to resolve as you cannot flow right on one row then left for overflow

Comment: . If the display order is the only issue, by which I mean you don't care which div appears where, then flow row reverse might be an option

Comment: if you keep grid-auto-flow column, that means the 2nd element is the first of second row. You just put an empty div in your html, second place

Comment: Yea I was not aware of how grid-auto-flow works. Read about it and it made sense. I ended up using flex box by. created one parent and two child divs. gave flex-direction column to parent and on child divs, then i set the layout up as desired.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is currently a built-in way using CSS grid layout to layout the items the way you have in the first photo.

You should either manually order the items in the order that you want them to be displayed (inserting padding cells/items where necessary), replace grid with 2 flexboxes, or you can create a custom element that describes how you want them ordered with JavaScript.

Here is an example of a custom element that achieves what you want:

```js
class CardGrid extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.attachShadow({
      mode: "open"
    });
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = /*html*/ `<slot id="slot"></slot>`;
  }

  #createRow() {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style = "display: grid; grid-auto-flow: column; grid-auto-columns: 1fr; gap: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;";
    return div;
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    const slot = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#slot");

    // listen for when children are added/modified
    slot.addEventListener("slotchange", () => {
      const children = slot.assignedElements();

      const row1 = this.#createRow();
      const row2 = this.#createRow();

      const firstRowEndIndex = Math.ceil(children.length / 2);
      const firstRowChildren = children.slice(0, firstRowEndIndex);
      const secondRowChildren = children.slice(firstRowEndIndex);
      if (firstRowChildren > secondRowChildren) {
        // add padding cell
        const paddingCell = document.createElement("div");
        secondRowChildren.unshift(paddingCell)
      }

      const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
      wrapper.style.display = "inline-block";
      row1.append(...firstRowChildren);
      row2.append(...secondRowChildren);
      wrapper.append(row1, row2);
      this.append(wrapper);
    }, {
      once: true
    });
  }
}

customElements.define("card-grid", CardGrid)
```

```css
.box {
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: var(--color);
}

.r {
  --color: red
}

.o {
  --color: orange
}

.y {
  --color: yellow
}

.g {
  --color: green
}

.b {
  --color: blue
}

.i {
  --color: indigo
}

.v {
  --color: violet
}
```

```html
<card-grid>
  <div class="box r"></div>
  <div class="box o"></div>
  <div class="box y"></div>
  <div class="box g"></div>
  <div class="box b"></div>
  <div class="box i"></div>
  <div class="box v"></div>
  <div class="box r"></div>
  <div class="box o"></div>
  <div class="box y"></div>
  <div class="box g"></div>
</card-grid>
```